# How to test my linq repository calls

Tags: unit-testing, linq-to-sql, tdd

I have the following UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<Entities.User> {

public Entities.IUser Find(string domain, string username, string password) {
            return (from u in FindAll()
                    where u.Account.SubDomain == domain && u.EmailAddress == username && u.PasswordHash == password
                    && !u.IsArchived
                    select u).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
```

The "FindAll" method is part of Repository and basically just calls context.GetTable().AsQueryable()

I want to be able to write a test that will call this repository method but instead of accessing the database use some in-memory store.

I have done lots of searching and everything I seem to come across talks about mocking the repository out and returning a List (usually created at the start of the unit test) instead but what I don't understand is what use is that. I want to make sure that the linq query I have written is actually filtering the objects correctly and retrieving only the required records.
As the DataContext doesn't have an interface I can't simply mock that out.

The only other way I can see handling this is to actually talk to the db but I know this isn't the point of unit testing.

My question is how have others handled this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel Higarths last comment above where he mentioned Moles this helped me to solve the issue along with the following video http://dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an interface to mock things. You could easily create a mock that derives from `DataContext` and pass that into your repository.

Comment: And how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What is your problem? Creating a mock class that derives from DataContext? `class MockDataContext : DataContext { /* ... */ }` or injecting it into the repository?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all this. Are you saying that I should create this MockDataContext and then using StructureMap inject this where my usual datacontext is used? Would that then enable me to use moq to say when gettable is called on my normal datacontext to just return an iqueryable list of the objects I require, that way I'm not actually talking to a live database.

Comment: @Gazeth: I had a look at the DataContext class. Not all public members are virtual (in fact, most are not), so **no**, you can't use Moq to create that mock. In this case, the best way would be to use Moles or TypeMock to intercept the calls to DataContext and to provide a mock.

Comment: Would that not be a fake rather than a mock?

Comment: @nixon: I don't know - or care. I don't see the benefit of using different names for the same thing. That's actually the reason why I use NSubstitute.